# Modify "string" value inside txt doc

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I Read a text document with readFile method ,and I got the current string.
I need to modify some specific fields inside and save the file and keep the original format

in the read file I got the following string and I need to change just the number for property **INSTANCE_ADDR** the value from 3000 to 4000 and keep it in the same format,the problem is that the value 3000 can be any number so I need to finde the key **INSTANCE_ADDR** and then somehow to update the value and keep it in same format,how  should I do that ?

```
"BASH_VERSINFO=([0]=\"3\" [1]=\"2\" [2]=\"51\" [3]=\"1\" [4]=\"release\" [5]=\"x86_64-suse-linux-gnu\")\r\nBASH_VERSION='3.2.51(1)-release'\r\nINSTANCE_ADDR=10.97.27.7:3000\r\\r\n"
```

I use the `fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8')` and the response is this content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(INSTANCE_ADDR=[^:]*):\d+
```

Try this.Replace by `$1:4000` See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/55

```
var re = /(INSTANCE_ADDR=[^:]*):\d+/gi; 
var str = '"BASH_VERSINFO=([0]=\"3\" [1]=\"2\" [2]=\"51\" [3]=\"1\" [4]=\"release\" [5]=\"x86_64-suse-linux-gnu\")\r\nBASH_VERSION=\'3.2.51(1)-release\'\r\nINSTANCE_ADDR=10.97.27.7:3000\r\\r\n"';
var subst = '$1:4000'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

For internal

```
var re = /(CF_INSTANCE_PORTS='\[.*?internal):\d+/gi; 
var str = 'CF_INSTANCE_PORTS=\'[{external:50100,internal:50100}]';
var subst = '$1:12312'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: Thanks 1+ but how should I test it against this string can you provide example please?:let say I got this string as variable...

Comment: Ok thanks but the value (4000) is coming from varible so how should I put it?

Comment: @JohnJerrby you can add the varirable to `$1:` and assign to `subst`

Comment: Do you mean like '$1:' + value ?

Comment: @JohnJerrby is it not working?it works in python that way

Comment: yep its working thanks a lot I 've additional question on the same topic assume that i've additional property like  INSTANCE_PORTS='[{external:50100,internal:50100}]' and I need to update the internal value only (change to 400)how can I do that?can you assist please?

Comment: Thanks a lot can you please also update how to do it in code as answer?thanks a lot sir!

Comment: Thanks you are great! i've additional question regard the same topic but ill open in few min new question and I hope you can help thanks again!