# Modify specific text with value

Tags: javascript, regex

I Read a text document with readFile method ,and I got the current string.
I need to modify some specific fields inside and save the file and keep the original format

in the read file I got the following "string"

```
\r\nAPP_HOST=mo-d6fa.corp\r\nAPP_PORT=5000\r\nINS_PORT=50100\r\nPORT=66000\r\n
```

and I need to change just the number for properties

1. PORT=4000
2. APP_PORT =4000

I use the `fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8')` and the response is this file

Comment: Why can't you modify *a bit* [this answer to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32058890/3832970)? Try `(\nPORT\s*=\s*)\d+` and `\nAPP_PORT\s*=\s*)\d+`. And same `$1NEWVALUE` in replacement.

Comment: @stribizhev - can you provide it as answer please?

Comment: @stribizhev - The problem is with the port since I can have lots of fields with ports like ( PORT1, PORT7  PORTS_TEST _PORT) and I need to find exactly the PORT field

Comment: I have added my answer that is a bit different (since it was already taken by Akash).

Comment: @JohnJerrby Can I edit your question's title to reflect that you were looking to easily alter settings?  I believe this Q&A will be more useful if we turn the title to something more meaningful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify it turning into an object, setting values and then get back to string using [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var rawValues = "\r\nAPP_HOST=mo-d6fa.corp\r\nAPP_PORT=5000\r\nINS_PORT=50100\r\nPORT=66000\r\n";

// #1 You need to turn raw string into an array using String.prototype.split
// #2 It's time to reduce the array into an object to be able to access
// config values as a key-value pair store
var values = rawValues.trim().split("\r\n").reduce(
  function(result, next, index, sourceArray) {
    var keyValuePair = sourceArray[index].split("=");
    result[keyValuePair[0]] = keyValuePair[1];

    return result;
  }, {});


// Now you can alter config values like a dictionary:
values["PORT"] = "9995";
values["APP_PORT"] = "9999";
// or using dot syntax if possible settings have valid JavaScript
// variable names...
values.PORT = "9995";
values.APP_PORT = "9999";
// ...more settings...

// #3 Once you've edited your settings, it's time to reduce each property
// as part of a new raw string containing all configurations.
rawValues = Object.keys(values).reduce(function(previousValue, property, index) {
  previousValue += property + "=" + values[property] + "\r\n";

  return previousValue;
}, "");


// Now PORT and APP_PORT contain their new values...
document.getElementById("rawResult").textContent = JSON.stringify(rawValues);
```

```html
<div id="rawResult"></div>
```

### Suggestion

IMHO, if you can turn your configuration into a valid JSON life can be even easier.

For example, your raw config can be `{ "APP_HOST": "mo-d6fa.corp", "APP_PORT": 5000, "INS_PORT": 50100, "PORT": 66000 }`. See how this simplifies your problem:

```js
var rawConfig = '{ "APP_HOST": "mo-d6fa.corp", "APP_PORT": 5000, "INS_PORT": 50100, "PORT": 66000 }';
var config = JSON.parse(rawConfig);
config["APP_PORT"] = 6000;
config["PORT"] = 7000;
rawConfig = JSON.stringify(config);

document.getElementById("result").textContent = rawConfig;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Instead of rolling your own configuration parser, you can just use JSON which is a well-known pattern and it has a built-in, out-of-the-box parser as part of every Web browser in the earth, NodeJS and even non-JavaScript platforms like .NET, Java...

Answer (score 1):

The regexes for both these will be pretty similar. Here's a stab:

```
var portRegex = /\nPORT=\d+/g;
var appPortRegex = /\nAPP_PORT=\d+/g;

var fileStr = fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8');
fileStr = fileStr
    .replace(portRegex, '\nPORT=' + 4000)
    .replace(appPortRegex, '\nAPP_PORT=' + 4000);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with finding the exact `PORT` entry can be resolved by matching it at the beginning of a line only with `/m` modifier (in a multiline mode) that forces `^` to match at the beginning of a line:

```
/^(PORT\s*=\s*)\d+/m
/^(APP_PORT\s*=\s*)\d+/m
```

```js
var re = /^(APP_PORT\s*=\s*)\d+/m; 
var re2 = /^(PORT\s*=\s*)\d+/m; 
var str = 'APP_HOST=mo-d6fa.corp\nAPP_PORT=5000\nINS_PORT=50100\nPORT=66000';
var result = str.replace(re, '$1NEWVALUE').replace(re2, '$1ANOTHERVALUE');
document.write(result);
```